# Detect HTML 5 "drop" event in Flex wrapper without "wmode=opaque"

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I would like to catch the HTML 5 "**dragenter**", "**dragover**" and "**drop**" event on a full page Flex application. The idea is to be able to drag & drop files from local system on the page and process it with JavaScript, and then send the data to Flex via **ExternalInterface**.

The problem is that I cannot catch those events on HTML elements as Flash Player is rendered over them and totally ignores z-index with default wmode. Changing wmode to opaque resolves the issue but I cannot use it as it is causing problems with text input special characters.

Does anyone know how to do it without putting `wmode=opaque` in the HTML wrapper?

P.S. While hovering Flex content, mouse cursor does change to indicate "drop impossible", I hope there is an event to catch related to that action. The idea is to catch any possible available HTML event and hide Flex content prior to drop operation.

TIA

Comment: The past general rule of the thumb is that you can't do what you want to do b/c Flash doesn't support it.  I'm theorizing a bit; but can you use a Flex iFrame component to provide an "HTML5 draggable area" that can handle the drag and drop from the desktop?

Comment: Flex iFrame also need wmode=opaque unless I'm missing your point? https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide

Comment: @Adrian Doric Nope; I think you understood my point.  Sorry; I never used it and wasn't aware of that implementation detail.

Comment: Now I'm trying to catch any HTML event (in order to hide Flex completely prior to drop) but nothing seems to pass, pure madness. Question edited.